# How to set an image next to the QTabBar in PyQt5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

I would like to add an image next to the QTabBar, where there are no tabs:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAisb.png)

I tried adding it as an image background but it doesn't do what I want to. I've been trying a lot of things during the past days but I am unable to do it. Can you help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `"...it is a company project so I cannot show the app"`: that shouldn't prevent you from providing a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem though.

Comment: Ok, you're right. I will do it in a minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably make use of [`QTabWidget::setCornerWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html#setCornerWidget)...

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class Widget(QtWidgets.QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QTabWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setCornerWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel("Corner Widget"))
        self.addTab(QtWidgets.QLabel("Tab 1"), "Tab 1")
        self.addTab(QtWidgets.QLabel("Tab 2"), "Tab 2")
        self.addTab(QtWidgets.QLabel("Tab ..."), "Tab ...")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Oh that worked perfectly! Thank you very much, I didn't know that QTabWidgets also had corner widgets.